# Firebase auth - how to un-protect listCollectionIds method in REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It seems that I can use the [get method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get?authuser=0) without any authorisation, but `listCollectionIds` needs some key to access, as I'm getting the 403 error without it.

I am able to access that data when I'm using the OAuth 2.0 on Google's API Explorer utility.

Firestore security rules are currently set to allow everything. Is there a way to disable authentication for `listCollectionIds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot list collections using client SDKs or remove any restrictions on it. Only the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) can access the `listCollections()` method using service accounts. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) says,

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

That being said, the best you can do is store list of collections (or sub-collections) in a document somewhere else in the database.

Other way around this would be creating a cloud function that'll fetch list of collections on behalf of your users.

```
exports.getCollections = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Authorize user if needs 
  const collections = await admin.firestore().listCollections()
  return collections
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I wish they had this explanation for the REST API documentation, but I would assume the same logic for the SDK applies

Comment: Also burned a few hours on this because I was only referencing the REST api.